# Apple Script Won't "Click" No Button

Tags: applescript, click

I have used Accessibility Inspector to confirm the names of the windows and buttons involved, but (on macOS 10.12) AppleScript will not "click" the No button in this Logitech window. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

```
tell application "Logitech Camera Settings"
activate
end tell
delay 5
tell application "System Events"
    click button "No" of window "Logitech Camera Settings" of application process "Logitech Camera Settings"
end tell
```

[image: Screenshot of Logitech Window AND Accessibility Inspector]

Comment: Do you get an error message alongside the button not being clicked?

Comment: Did you give your script accessibility access? If you didn't, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the sheet is missing in the element hierarchy in your AppleScript.

```
click button "No" of sheet 1 of window "Logitech Camera Settings" of application process "Logitech Camera Settings"
```